# float after startsection adds whitespace (ConTeXt)

Tags: context, white-space

When I add a float straight after a section heading in ConTeXt for some reason additional whitespace is added.

In this MWE it is not very pronounced, but in some of my documents it looks quite strange.

```
\setupwhitespace
    [big]

\starttext

\startsection
     [title=section]

\startplacefigure
     [location={right},
      title={just a dummy figure}]
    \externalfigure[dummy][width=.5\textwidth]
\stopplacefigure

PARAGRAPH 1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus 
sed cursus massa. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum nec tellus sit amet metus porttitor bibendum. Vestibulum viverra lacus libero, eget volutpat libero commodo sed. Donec sapien velit, feugiat in interdum sed, suscipit ac ex. Nam dignissim feugiat ipsum, sed suscipit erat congue vel. Nulla facilisi. Nunc et quam ultrices lectus vehicula tincidunt et eu ipsum.

PARAGRAPH 2 Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam eu dignissim odio. Etiam in pringilla libero. Pellentesque semper arcu accumsan, placerat diam in, sodales tellus. Vestibulum consectetur lacinia gravida. Nunc porta, tellus eget convallis ornare, justo nisl placerat nunc, sed accumsan tortor arcu suscipit magna. Donec dictum sapien ut turpis accumsan consectetur. Sed finibus dapibus ligula. Fusce non mauris consectetur, condimentum neque quis, malesuada risus. 

\stopsection

\stoptext
```

Is this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug.  You can work around it by temporarily restore the default whitespacing (`none`) for the paragraph with the wrapped figure.

Reported on the mailing list https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/091144.html

---

EDIT: Hans posted a fix on the mailing list, which works with the latest beta.

```
\unprotect
\def\page_sides_wrapup
   {% we need to do this aftergroup
    \aftergroup\par
    \aftergroup\ignoreparskip
    \aftergroup\ignorespaces
    }
\protect
```

---

I seem to recall that there have been other issues in the past when starting a section with a wrapped figure.  I cannot give you any sources from the top of my head, but to avoid problems you shouldn't start a section with a wrapped figure.

```
\setupwhitespace[big]

\starttext

\startsection
  [title=section]

  % Set default whitespace
  \setupwhitespace[none]

  \startplacefigure
    [location={right},
      title={just a dummy figure}]
    \externalfigure[dummy][width=.5\textwidth]
  \stopplacefigure

  \input lorem

  % Restore whitespace
  \setupwhitespace[big]

  \input lorem

\stopsection

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thanks Henri. That workaround will work for now. It actually appears to work just fine if I just wrap the float with different setupwhitespace options. The same issue occurs in itemized lists (starthead) and the workaround works there as well